# new google map: LatLng not a number, but I think it is

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

### Trying to get this working - https://clinicalthermography.co.nz/test_map.php

e.g. the 1st location logs as

```
"Object
Lat: -36.768498
Lng: 174.75895"
```

### But the error says lat not a number.  Rather than fiddle blindly, this newby would like to understand why it's not and what it is :-)

```
var map, marker;

function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var centerOfNZ = {lat: -40.8, lng: 173.0};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5.9,
        center: centerOfNZ
    });

    markAllLocations ();
}

function markAllLocations () {
    var locations = [
        ['Auckland','Milford Health Clinic, 50 East Coast Road, Milford', -36.768498, 174.75895],
        ['Christchurch',     'The George, 50 Park Terrace, Christchurch', -43.525776, 172.628387],
        ['Dunedin',          'Aurora on George, 678 George St,   Dunedin', -45.876251, 170.502548],
        ['Hamilton ',        'Medcom Integrative Health Clinic, 32 O\'Neill St, Claudelands,  Hamilton', -37.781234, 175.288198],
        ['Hawke\'s Bay',      'The Doctors Greenmeadows, 524 Kennedy Rd,  Greenmeadows,  Napier', -39.5229328, 176.8685695],
        ['Invercargill',     'The Quest Serviced Apartments, 10 Dee St,  Cnr Dee and Tay Streets,  Invercargill', -46.4131866, 168.3537731],
        ['Nelson',           'Delorenzos Apartments, 43\-55 Trafalgar St,  The Wood,  Nelson', -41.267575, 173.287417],
        ['New Plymouth',     'Quality Hotel Plymouth, Cnr of Courtney and Leach St,  New Plymouth', -39.061173, 174.06889],
        ['Palmerston North', 'Cornwall Motor Lodge, 101 Fitzherbert Avenue,  Palmerston North', -40.3596103, 175.6141897],
        ['Queenstown',       'Level One, 5 Duke St,  Queenstown', -45.03135700, 168.65935960],
        ['Tauranga',         '1416A Cameron Rd Greerton,  Tauranga', -37.729565, 176.129608],
        ['Wanaka',           'C/- Janice Cleghorne, 143 Hunter Cres,  Wanaka', -44.697945,169.167267],
        ['Wellington',       'The Quest on Thorndon, 61\-63 Thorndon Quay,  Thorndon,  Wellington', -41.2760045, 174.7813852],
        ['Whangarei',        'Distinction Whangarei Hotel, 9 Riverside Drive,  Riverside,  Whangarei', -35.723466, 174.327632]
    ];

    for (let count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
        let myPos = {                     
                Lat : locations[count][2],
                Lng : locations[count][3]
        };
        console.log(
            count + '  ' + locations[count][0] 
        );
        console.log(myPos);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            { map : map,
              position: myPos,  
              title: locations[count][0] 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: see how you have `centerOfNZ = {lat: -40.8, lng: 173.0}` and you make `let myPos = {                     
                Lat : locations[count][2],
                Lng : locations[count][3]
        };`  ... can you see a difference?

Comment: @Jaromanda X - ta.  I find that sort of thing hard to find, do you know of any tool that helps to find that sort of thing?  (I've recently started using Visual St. Code...

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API `Marker()` needs to be passed a `position` object with `lng` and `lat` keys which both have number values. In your case, you have an object `myPos` which has `Lat` and `Lng` (capitalized), and you are getting an error because `myPos.lat === undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There was, as you have perhaps by now figured out, a small discrepency in spelling which was leading to the error you were experiencing. The correct spellings are `lat` and `lng` ~ all lowercase as opposed to capitalised. That said it wouldn't hurt to cast the variables as numbers when calling them by using `parseFloat(var)` or using the google maps method `new google.maps.LatLng(_LAT_,_LNG_)`

As I had a little spare time I played around with the original code slightly as you'll see below - hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps: New Zealand - Clinical Thermography</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body,
            html { height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box; }
            #map { width:90%;height:90vh; margin:auto;float:none; }
            /* hide infowindow & pre-format content */
            #info{display:none; padding:1rem;margin:0.25rem;border:1px solid pink;background:white;}
            #info div{margin:0.5rem auto;}
            #info div:before{content:attr(data-label)":";text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;color:black;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;}
            #info div:after{content:attr(data-value);color:pink;}
        </style>
        <script>
            let map;
            let marker;
            let infoWindow;
            let geocoder;
            let content;

            function initMap() {
                const centerOfNZ = {
                        lat: -40.8,
                        lng: 173.0
                    };
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 5.9,
                    center: centerOfNZ
                });

                /* The Geocoder is not used */
                //geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth:350, disableAutoPan:false });
                infoWindow.setContent( document.getElementById('info') );

                markAllLocations();
            }

            function markAllLocations () {
                let locations = [
                    ['Auckland',            'Milford Health Clinic, 50 East Coast Road, Milford', -36.768498, 174.75895],
                    ['Christchurch',        'The George, 50 Park Terrace, Christchurch', -43.525776, 172.628387],
                    ['Dunedin',             'Aurora on George, 678 George St,   Dunedin', -45.876251, 170.502548],
                    ['Hamilton ',           'Medcom Integrative Health Clinic, 32 O\'Neill St, Claudelands,  Hamilton', -37.781234, 175.288198],
                    ['Hawke\'s Bay',        'The Doctors Greenmeadows, 524 Kennedy Rd,  Greenmeadows,  Napier', -39.5229328, 176.8685695],
                    ['Invercargill',        'The Quest Serviced Apartments, 10 Dee St,  Cnr Dee and Tay Streets,  Invercargill', -46.4131866, 168.3537731],
                    ['Nelson',              'Delorenzos Apartments, 43\-55 Trafalgar St,  The Wood,  Nelson', -41.267575, 173.287417],
                    ['New Plymouth',        'Quality Hotel Plymouth, Cnr of Courtney and Leach St,  New Plymouth', -39.061173, 174.06889],
                    ['Palmerston North',    'Cornwall Motor Lodge, 101 Fitzherbert Avenue,  Palmerston North', -40.3596103, 175.6141897],
                    ['Queenstown',          'Level One, 5 Duke St,  Queenstown', -45.03135700, 168.65935960],
                    ['Tauranga',            '1416A Cameron Rd Greerton,  Tauranga', -37.729565, 176.129608],
                    ['Wanaka',              'C/- Janice Cleghorne, 143 Hunter Cres,  Wanaka', -44.697945,169.167267],
                    ['Wellington',          'The Quest on Thorndon, 61\-63 Thorndon Quay,  Thorndon,  Wellington', -41.2760045, 174.7813852],
                    ['Whangarei',           'Distinction Whangarei Hotel, 9 Riverside Drive,  Riverside,  Whangarei', -35.723466, 174.327632]
                ];

                /* easier to use `forEach` as the source is an array */
                locations.forEach( location => {
                    /*
                        use `parseFloat` to cast the string to a number/float
                        Alternatively, use `new google.maps.LatLng(location[2],location[3])` 
                        which will do it all nicely for you
                    */
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                        map : map,
                        title: location[0],
                        description:location[1],
                        position: {
                            lat: parseFloat( location[2] ),
                            lng: parseFloat( location[3] )
                        }
                    });
                    /* show info for each marker when clicked */
                    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
                        /* get a reference to the infowindow content */
                        content=infoWindow.getContent();
                        /* ensure the content is visible */
                        content.style.display='block';
                        /* add details from marker to the content */
                        content.querySelector('[data-label="name"]').dataset.value=this.title;
                        content.querySelector('[data-label="description"]').dataset.value=this.description;
                        content.querySelector('[data-label="co-ordinates"]').dataset.value=[this.position.lat(),this.position.lng()].join(', ');
                        /* display content */
                        infoWindow.setPosition( e.latLng );
                        infoWindow.open( map );
                    });
                });

            }
        </script>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap' async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='map'></div>
      <!-- use a hidden element as the content for the infoWindow content -->
      <div id='info'>
        <div data-label='name' data-value=''></div>
        <div data-label='description' data-value=''></div>
        <div data-label='co-ordinates' data-value=''></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd bumbled on a bit and got as far as displaying the infoWindows (iw), but (yay) I can see good stuff in your V helpful code that I will definitely use/absorb after I understand this new issue  ...

Comment: New issue:  in my current version ( see https://codepen.io/Ognik/pen/YBVBZy?editors=1111) , I have the markers showing, and in each iteration I store the iw content in that marker.
Then I can set the listener once only, using 'this' to recover the iw content for the current marker.
line 23 works, showing the correct position but the next line (infoWindow.setPosition(this.position) doesn't seem to execute.  While I will modify my code with your suggestions, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong at this point please?

Comment: a quick look at your version on codepen is incorrect. the event listener is bound to the last marker only in your code rather than to each marker. The codepen demo though does not work ( at least, not for me )

Comment: Yes codepen doesn' run, don''t know why.  I am using it as an easy way to share my latest code.  If anyone knows why it doesn't disaply the map, which display when run in a browser, I'd be interested.  There is so much to learn :-)

Comment: The way the marker is intended to work, is to bind the listener to whichever marker was clicked - the clicked marker becomes 'this' (I think)  I checked it with console.log('not open  iw=  ' + this.info); which displays the correct info in console.

Comment: AT the moment I see all the logs until line 26 - infoWindow.setPosition(this.position);  The log immediately after it doesn't show, and clicking other markers doesn't show any other logs - so effectively it freezes on infoWindow.setPosition(this.position);

Comment: I had a thought - codepen might not be working because of the API key; google sees codepen as an unauthorised source?

Comment: forget about why codepen is not workin - the code is essentially not correct. You need to assign a listener for each marker ( either when created or later for all ) - the code you have assigns the listener once for the last marker only. Analyse the code I posted - it works, apply what you see to your own code. One other thing: the `locations` array ~ if you have control over it's generation it would be easier in some respects to use an `object literal` rather than an array - that's just my opinion though

Comment: For my understanding please:
1.why do you have '...new google.maps.InfoWindow...' before markAllLocations(); instead of in the loop?
2. What does 'infoWindow.setContent( document.getElementById('info') );' do?

Comment: What I was trying to do with the infoWindows: 
The loop creates all the markers.  When a marker is clicked, it is the 'this' keyword.  So I was going to only create the infoWindow each time a marker was clicked, and get the content, position etc. from 'this.'   Please let me understand why that isn't possible?

Comment: It is possible ( not very efficient to create a new infowindow each time ) but your code ( on codepen ) doesn't even do that. The `click` event listener needs to be attached to `EVERY` marker and somewhere youneed to actually create the new `infoWindow` object... in your case, if I understood correctly, you would create the infoWindow in the `click` callback function. I just ran you code locally - only the last marker accepts the click event and then it fails with an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined` ~ I see though now that the live version appears to work

Comment: 'Cos codepen didn't run, I didn't update it - should I instead be updating the code where I pasted the original?  (not sure of that protocol).
Yes, working - using your approach, and I appreciate your help :-)  I still have stuff I'm trying to understand though...